# Is this normal in the software-industry?

Tags: software-industry, software-development

I'm sure about the vague title but I was not sure how to post this question.

My situation is the following. I have been working in a company for about 10 months now, and I was hired as a junior (java) software engineer after finishing my uni degree. The company I am working for now is a company with almost no communication in the software team. We have about 6 juniors and 3 seniors (rather small company). We have a chatclient for communication (and questions) yet it is hardly used, and when someone does use it, not often something valuable comes out of the short exchange of words. (Which is on the order of two times a week)

The lack of communication is one thing that struck me as a bit odd. In addition we don't seem to employ design patterns or other common software engineering practices. (If the code layout is messed up for example, they would rather leave it that way than taking a few minutes to fix it). And furthermore, I feel like I am not learning anything new at this job.

Lastly, and perhaps my main issue, is that even though I am hired as a java developer, I spend programming maybe half a day to one day a week. The rest of the week, I spend doing HTML/CSS design, or changing some config files.

I was wondering if this is normal for the software industry, or perhaps this is more a characteristic of small companies? Would it be different in larger companies?

Comment: No, that is weird and broken.

Comment: "If the code layout is messed up for example, they would rather leave it that way than taking a few minutes to fix it" - if you mean just formatting, then that can happen on large code bases with many branches in development at once, because the danger is that formatting changes will break everyone's merges. If you want to make formatting changes you have to pick a moment when everyone's stuff is checked in e.g. around a release, and where you don't have too many stable branches on the old formatting to back-port fixes from head to.

Comment: would this be better for http://stackoverflow.com/ or would it be OT there?

Comment: This is a sign of bad management, hopefully it will improve in time.

Comment: "If the code layout is messed up for example, they would rather leave it that way than taking a few minutes to fix it" - this could also indicate lack of tests. For example, if there is not a good test suite, a developer can't always be confident that "formatting changes" didn't inadvertently introduce bugs.

Comment: Look, when you said you're not learning new things but its working with HTML/CSS and Java, I think its a good thing. In my first job I didnt have any xp before. I was hire to work with Android/Java, but in my first 6 months I was working with Fullstack Web (Html,Css,Php,Js). I did my best, and after this months I asked for my boss to give me a chance to work with Android. Now I see that time was so important to me. Look, I'm a Mobile developer with xp in web development. My resume looks really good

Comment: Try to use this things to grow as a developer. We need to learn new things everyday. Your profession changes so fast and its really important to know more than 1 programming language, here in my country is a obligation tbh

Answer (score 7):

First of all, when you're hired as a developer on a small (or small-ish) team, you're almost definitely going to wear many hats (meaning you will assume the duties of multiple job titles at once), so the fact that you're doing HTML/CSS is not surprising.

The communication strangeness and the fact that it seems like good methodologies aren't being used sound like it perhaps is simply a very 'new' development team entirely.

So to clarify: "Is this normal?" - Somewhat

PS: You should write up something professional and polite to address your concerns about processes and methodologies and talk to your superiors about it!  If they are a good team they will welcome good ideas and 'proper' programming!

Comment: I would be careful about "writing up something professional and polite..." and sending to superiors. Change happens gradually and it's often better to pick your spots strategically, rather than trying to sum up everything that's wrong in a given environment. Often people already know what's wrong, but don't have the time/support to correct it.

Comment: @mcknz Absolutely true.  It depends on the team and the personalities I suppose.  I've been on teams where this sort of thing would have been welcomed with open arms, and I have at least interacted with teams where this would have set you on the path to getting pushed out the door.  *User discretion is advised*

Answer (score 5):

Although the situation as you describe is not ideal, and certainly not "normal," unfortunately it's not uncommon, especially among smaller companies. Companies can start small, with employees who teach themselves software development, and build homegrown systems.

What you are seeing is classic [technical debt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt) -- design decisions are made for short-term goals, rather than long-term maintainability.

You would likely see better development practices at a larger company, but there are trade-offs -- for the most part, at a smaller company you get to do more things more quickly. At a large company development can be more specialized and subject to layers of (sometimes necessary) bureaucracy.

You're gaining valuable experience not only in hands-on coding, but ***lessons on what not do to*** in the future. As long as you are trying to apply sound practices and encouraging others to do the same, you and your team can improve.

If the situation doesn't get better gradually however, you may want to look for other opportunities -- it can be frustrating and stressful when you know the right way to work, but the company culture doesn't allow it.